# How does a http client associate an http response with a request (with Netty) or in general?

Tags: http, nio, netty

Is a http end point suppose to respond to requests from a particular client in order that they are received?

What about if it doesn't make sense to in the case of requests handled by cluster behind a proxy or in requests handled with NIO where one request is finished faster than the other?

Is there a standard way of associating a unique id with each http request to associate with the response? How is this handled in clients like http componenets httpclient or curl?

The question comes down to the following case:

Suppose, I am downloading a file from a server and the request is not finished. Is a client capable of completing other requests on the same keep-alive connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't re-write CodeCaster's answer because it is very well worded.

In response to your edit - no. It is not. A single persistent HTTP connection can only be used for one request at once, or it would get very confusing. Because HTTP does not define any form of request/response tracking mechanism, it simply would not be possible.

It should be noted that there are other protocols which use a similar message format (conforming to [RFC822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt)), which do allow for this (using mechanisms such as [SIP's cSeq header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-8.1.1.5)), and it would be possible to implement this in a custom HTTP app, but HTTP does not define any standard mechanism for doing this, and therefore nothing can be done that could be assumed to work everywhere. It would also present a problem with the response for the second message - do you wait for the first response to finish before sending the second response, or try and pause the first response while you send the second response? How will you communicate this in a way that guarantees messages won't become corrupted?

Note also that SIP (usually) operates over UDP, which does not guarantee packet ordering, making the cSeq system more of a necessity.

If you want to send a request to a server while another transaction is still in progress, you will need to create a new connection to the server, and hence a new TCP stream.

Facebook did some research into this while they were building their CDN, and they concluded that you can efficiently have 2 or 3 open HTTP streams at any one time, but any more than that reduces overall transfer time because of the extra packet overhead cost. I would link to the blog entry if I could find the link...

Answer (score 5):

Whenever a TCP connection is opened, the connection is recognized by the source and destination ports and IP addresses. So if I connect to www.google.com on destination port 80 (default for HTTP), I need a free source port which the OS will generate.

The reply of the web server is then sent to the source port (and IP). This is also how NAT works, remembering which source port belongs to which internal IP address (and vice versa for incoming connections).

As for your edit: no, a single http connection can execute one command (GET/POST/etc) at the same time. If you send another command while you are retreiving data from a previously issued command, the results may vary per client and server implementation. I guess that Apache, for example, will transmit the result of the second request after the data of the first request is sent.

Comment: +1 - Nice succinct explaination. Altoid Muncher, I think you might do well to [read up on some of the basics of TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol), the transport layer protocol that HTTP (usually) operates on. Relatively high-level software such as a web browser or cURL does not have to worry about this, it is handled by the underlying TCP/IP stack of the operating system. For further reading that is closely related to this, as @CodeCaster mentioned, read up on [NAT (Network Address Translation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)

Comment: +1 for the nice answer.
A caveat: a single HTTP connection *can* execute multiple requests, when using HTTP Pipelining (wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining, example: http://info-chaitra.blogspot.com/2011/03/http-persistent-connection.html). The catch is that the requests must be idempotent: GETs are fine, but no POSTs.

Comment: @LucaInvernizzi true, but the server will not send multiple resources at the same time, it's still FIFO: the data of the second response will be sent after all the data of first response has been sent. There is no multiplexing, as there is in SPDY for example. Oh, and don't say +1 when you don't upvote. ;-)